# Java Inheritance: Method set(List<Bean>) not applicable for arguments ArrayList<SubBean>

Tags: java, inheritance

I'm getting an error in the following.

Hierarchy: **GeneralBudgetBean -> RRBudgetBean.**

They contain data members with the following hierarchy: 
**GeneralBudgetYearBean -> RRBudgetYearBean**

Parent Class - GeneralBudgetBean.java

```
// Data member
private List<GeneralBudgetYearBean> budgetYearBeans;

// Getters/setters
    public List<GeneralBudgetYearBean> getBudgetYearBeans() {
        return budgetYearBeans;
    }

    public void setBudgetYearBeans(List<GeneralBudgetYearBean> budgetYearBeans) {
        this.budgetYearBeans = budgetYearBeans;
    }
```

**Extending Class - RRBudgetBean.java**

```
public class RRBudgetBean extends GeneralBudgetBean {
   //...

   public void initRRBudgetBean()
   {
       this.setBudgetYearBeans(new ArrayList<RRBudgetYearBean>());
   }

}
```

Error:

```
The method setBudgetYearBeans(List<GeneralBudgetYearBean>) in the type GeneralBudgetBean is not applicable for the arguments ArrayList<RRBudgetYearBean>
```

In other words, the error is:

```
Method method(List<Bean>) not applicable for arguments ArrayList<SubBean>.
```

Comment: `ArrayList<T>` does not extend `List<T>`

Comment: @NathanMerrill `List<T>` can still reference `ArrayList<T>` because it is implementing the `List` interface.

Comment: @NathanMerrill No, there's a subtype relationship there.

Comment: (Generally it's best to copy mutable values from arguments and before returning values.)

Comment: Try `setBudgetYUearBeans(List<? extends GeneralBudgetYearBean> budgetYearBeans)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From tutorial (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/inheritance.html):
`Box<Integer>` and `Box<Double>` are not subtypes of `Box<Number>`.

In that situation, you must change method signature to

```
public void setBudgetYearBeans(List<? extends GeneralBudgetYearBean> budgetYearBeans) {
    this.budgetYearBeans = budgetYearBeans;
}
```

That http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcardGuidelines.html article about wildcards might be useful.

Answer (score -3):

Change your

```
setBudgetYearBeans(List<GeneralBudgetYearBean> budgetYearBeans)
```

to

```
setBudgetYearBeans(ArrayList<GeneralBudgetYearBean> budgetYearBeans)
```

In general, it is a good practice to make your method argument type more specific and your method return values more general.

Comment: No offense, but this is bad advice.

Comment: -1 It's just the opposite. You should be more liberal about what you accept and more strict about what you return! Also this is not the correct answer to the question. The correct answer is given by @Rayan Ral

Comment: @SvetlinZarev why more strict with what you return?  I prefer to be liberal with both.

Comment: because if i return `Set` for example I can assign it to a variable of type `Collection`, but not the vice versa. My comment was about the use of interface/concrete implementation, not about the generics which he obviously didn't get right

Comment: @SvetlinZarev but couldn't he just return `Collection` and be more liberal?

Comment: He can, but to a given extent. I prefer to return interfaces too, not concrete implementations, but I'd also choose to return `List`/`Set`/Whatever over plain `Collection`, because if I return a `Set` I will  know that add/remove/contains will be  at most O(log N) ,while it can be anything for `Collection`. Also If I return TreeSet it means that the set is *ordered*, (the `List` can also be ordered), while I won't know that if I return `Collection`